# CSS: Best way to make floating navbar above hero image?

Tags: html, css

This was probably asked in a different way before, but I couldn't find any that answer this specifically.

I want to have a navbar that on a normal page is ABOVE the page content and on one with a hero image looks like it's WITHIN the page content.

I typically use Jinja2 templates (for Django) so manually putting the navbar into the page content doesn't make a lot of sense.

I currently use negative margins to do this, but it feels a bit hacky (checkout code below)

**EDIT:** The second navbar (where the Navbar background is BEHIND the hero background, but the Navbar text is IN FRONT of the hero background) is how I want it to be.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

:root {
  --primary: #21abde;
  --navbar-height: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  height: var(--navbar-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: white;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar ul a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.navbar ul a:hover {
  color: var(--primary);
}

.content,
.hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  background: darkcyan;
  height: calc(100vh - var(--navbar-height));
}

.hero {
  background: darkorange;
  margin-top: calc(-1*var(--navbar-height));
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">Navbar 1</div>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="content">
  Content
</div>
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">Navbar 2</div>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="hero">
  Hero
</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this or is this the only way that doesn't involve manually including the navbar into the page's content (As I feel like this doesn't make a lot of sense for anything other than a static navbar)?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. There is a better way. Just use [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

:root {
  --primary: #21abde;
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar ul a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.navbar ul a:hover {
  color: var(--primary);
}

.content,
.hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  background: darkcyan;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hero {
  background: darkorange;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">Navbar 1</div>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="content">
  Content
</div>
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">Navbar 2</div>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="hero">
  Hero
</div>
```

Comment: Actually this isn't what I was looking for. In my code there are 2 navbars and the second one where the Hero background goes IN FRONT OF the navbar background, but behind the navbar text is what I want.